# ¿Como puedo acceder a los atributos de este objeto en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, variables

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy renderizando configuraciones en una app, así que del ajax obtengo el este objeto.

Cuando intento leerlo no puedo dado que no se cual sea la sintaxis para hacerlo.

```
res.data.0-MenuComponent
res.data.'0-MenuComponent'
```

intente con esas dos he igual parseando el de esta forma

```
res.data.String('0-MenuComponent')
```

pero me regresa un error.

Comment: Intenta con esta `res.data["0-MenuComponent"]`

Answer (score 3):

La llave del JSON está violando las reglas de creación

> Choose meaningful property names. Property names must conform to the
>   following guidelines:
>
> Property names should be meaningful names with defined semantics.
>   Property names must be camel-cased, ascii strings. The first character
>   must be a letter, an underscore (_) or a dollar sign ($). Subsequent
>   characters can be a letter, a digit, an underscore, or a dollar sign.
>   Reserved JavaScript keywords should be avoided (A list of reserved
>   JavaScript keywords can be found below).

[Reglas JSON](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml)

Ahora para solventar lo que tienes ahora puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
res["data"]["0-MenuComponent"]
```

Utiliza siempre que puedas los índices, cómo dice la regla, un dígito no es soportado con la semántica que estás tratando de implementar.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Parsear el objeto a un array es brillante y ayer no se me ocurrió. Pero me diste una idea de que hacer. Lo que hice fue modificar el API para que solo regrese la configuración sin la llave con la que busca el objeto de configuraciones.